# $1-s + qp^rs^{r+1}$ has a unique positive root $s=x$.

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, proof-explanation, roots

(Feller Vol.1, P.323-324) Recurrent event occurs if a success run of length $r$ occurs. The author shows how to derive the distribution of recurrence times approximately. Let $F(s)$ be the generating function of this distribution, and  the author shows that
$$F(s) = \frac{p^rs^r(1-ps)}{1-s + qp^rs^{r+1}}.$$
The author is trying to derive $f_n$ (the probability that the first recurrence occurs at the $n$th trial; $F(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n s^n$), using the method of partial fractions. To do this, the author claims that "the equation in the display clearly shows that the denominator has a unique positive root $s=x$". I don't understand this statement. How do we know that $1-s+qp^rs^{r+1}$ has a unique positive root?

Comment: The denominator doesn't always have a unique positive root. If $r=1$ and $pq = \frac 3{16}$ for example, then the denominator is $1-s + \frac 3{16} s^2$ which has two positive roots $4$ and $\frac 43$. Is $p$ the success probability, with $q=1-p$? Then I got the above with $r=1,p=\frac 14$. Either you've copied wrong or there is some other issue.

Comment: Reading the text more closely, in the quoted phrase Feller is talking about a second representation in (7.6). This representation has the denominator $1 - qs \sum_{k = 0}^{r-1} (ps)^{k}$ which indeed has a unique single positive root. (This is unfortunately sloppy, yes, but the calculation of (7.9) is in fact dealing with 1 minus this object, so it is almost certainly the intended interpretation).